# What is the lowest version of Python that has the shutil module?

Tags: python, linux, shutil

I am trying to use `shutil.make_archive`, but I get a "module not found" error.

Then I tried using Python 2.7 and it worked.

What is the lowest Python version that contains that module and function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [shutil doc](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html), `make_archive` is new in version 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

shutil is at least as early as 2.3.  make_archive is new in 2.7. [shutil doc](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

Comment: I was able to find `shutil` in Python 1.5.2 but not in 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 is the earliest release to include `make_archive` in `shutils`. `shutils` in general existed since at least 2.0.